# iPhone: Storing audio data on NSUserDefaults and memory issues

Tags: iphone

I am downloading several small size songs from server and storing(NSData) into NSUserDefaults, so that i can use it when needed to cache and play directly on the device, instead of downloading and playing again from server.
The problem, if i store few couple of smaller size songs as an data format in NSUserDefaults, it reduces lots of device memory and throwing memory warning or crashing etc.

Could you someone guide me how can i resolve it? How can i store song data persistently on the device for Cache purpose, and same time storing in less memory usage?

**UPDATED:** As per the suggestion, i tried to add song data into dictionary as file and tried to retrieve it as below. But, still i'm facing the same issue, memory warning after around 30mb of data retrieved.. Could someone help me to resolve this? I need to store around 40 mb of song data and store it.

```
    NSURL *songurl = [NSURL URLWithString:downloadSOngUrl];
            NSMutableData *songdata = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:songurl];

NSString *fileName = [downloadSOngUrl lastPathComponent];
            NSLog(@"fileName: %@",fileName);

            [appDelegate writeSongIntoDocsDirectory :songdata :fileName];

-(void) writeSongIntoDocsDirectory :(NSData *) inSongData :(NSString *) songNamePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 

    NSLog(@"songNamePath: %@", songNamePath);

    songNamePath = [songNamePath stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] ];
    NSLog(@"songNamePath: %@", songNamePath);

    if ( [inSongData writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:songNamePath] atomically:YES] ) 
    {
        // Success !
        NSLog(@"Successfully saved the song into documents directory");

    } 
    else 
    {
        // Error !  
        NSLog(@"Error when Successfully saving song into documents directory");
    }
}
-(NSData *) readSongDataFromDocsDirectory :(NSString *) filePath
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 

    NSData *readData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath]];

    return readData;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Better store these audio files in documents directory as this will reduce the size of the app , NSUserDefaults is usually used to stored in small settings particular to the app , like the preferences and all for the particular user of the app. hoping this helps. . :)

Whatever you store in the NSUserDefaults will increase the app size as this object is always alive while the app runs...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. How are you saying to store audio files? I mean, what format? Do you want me store NSData of each song in documents directory? Because my songs urls are coming from server and i use NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; to get the song binary now.

Comment: NSData has a method called writeToFile:atomically: that does exactly what you want to do. Look in the documentation for NSData to see how to use it.

Comment: Hi, I added and storing into file in documents directory around 70 mb of song data, but the issue is same when i tried with NSUserDefaults as well.

Comment: Hi Mr.Ankit, i updated code my question, i'm observing the same issue still.